# Differential equation for a coil spring!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation of mass m on a coil spring with spring constant k in a medium in  which the damping is proportional to the instantaneous velocity given by

$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+a\frac{dx}{dt}+kx=0$$

Taking

$$2b=\frac{a}{m}$$

$$\lambda^2=\frac{k}{m}$$

In the case of damped oscillatory motion we have

$$x=ce^{-bt}\cos\left(\sqrt{\lambda^2-b^2}t+ \phi\right)$$

Show that the displacement x is defined to attain maximum or minimum at $t_n(n=1,2,3,4,5...)$ given by

$$t_n=\frac{1}{w_1}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{a}{-2mw_1}\right)+n\pi -\phi\right]$$

where

$$w_1=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}-\frac{a^2}{4m^2}}$$

This seems to be so scary.

Taking the derivative of x we have,

$$x'=-bce^{-bt}\cos(w_1t+ \phi)-w_1ce^{-bt}\sin(w_1t+ \phi)$$

By Fermat's theorem there exists relative extreme at $f'(x)=0$

$$0=-b\cos(w_1t+ \phi)-w_1s\in(w_1t+ \phi)$$

$$-\frac{b}{w_1}=\tan(w_1t+ \phi) $$

$$ w_1t+ \phi = \arctan\left(-\frac{b}{w_1}\right)$$

$$w_1t=\arctan\left(-\frac{b}{w_1}\right)-\phi $$

$$t=\frac{1}{w_1}\left[\arctan\left(-\frac{b}{w_1}\right)-\phi\right] $$

$$t=\frac{1}{w_1}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{a}{-2mw_1}\right) -\phi\right]$$

Where did the $n\pi$ comes from? I am missing it. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define the $\arctan$ function to be single valued, usually with values between $-\frac \pi 2$ and $\frac \pi 2$, but the tangent is periodic with values recurring at intervals of $\pi$.  When you took the arctangent of both sides you lost all but one of the solutions.  If you know $\tan x=1$ and try to solve for $x$ by taking the arctangent of both sides you will conclude $x=\frac \pi 4$, but in fact the solution is $x=\frac \pi 4 + n\pi$.  You can verify that by asking your calculator for $\tan \frac {9\pi}4$.  The principle is the same.